# Building a distribution with dependencies for Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I learning Spring development and trying to configure the Spring framework step by step following a project on Github (the website is: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Building-a-distribution-with-dependencies). After typing in the command `$ ./gradlew depsZip` to `Run the depsZip gradle task` . the following information was shown with a failure:

```
:spring-aspects:compileJava
Download http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.1/a
spectjrt-1.7.1.jar
[ant:iajc] C:\Users\Zihan\Documents\GitHub\spring-framework\spring-aspects\src\m
ain\java\org\springframework\beans\factory\aspectj\AbstractBeanConfigurerAspect.
aj:1 [error] The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectl
y referenced from required .class files
[ant:iajc] (no source information available)
[ant:iajc] C:\Users\Zihan\Documents\GitHub\spring-framework\spring-aspects\src\m
ain\java\org\springframework\mock\staticmock\AbstractMethodMockingControl.aj:19
[error] The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
[ant:iajc] import java.util.Arrays;
[ant:iajc]        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ant:iajc] C:\Users\Zihan\Documents\GitHub\spring-framework\spring-aspects\src\m
ain\java\org\springframework\mock\staticmock\AbstractMethodMockingControl.aj:87
[error] Arrays cannot be resolved
[ant:iajc] if (!Arrays.equals(this.args, args)) {
[ant:iajc]      ^
[ant:iajc]
[ant:iajc] 3 errors
:spring-aspects:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Zihan\Documents\GitHub\spring-framework\spring-aspects\aspects.
gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-aspects:compileJava'.
> compile errors: 3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 42.798 secs
C:\Users\Zihan\Documents\GitHub\spring-framework [(abdcefb...)]>
```

could any help me with the configuration problem. really appreciate if giving some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why you can't use a dependency managment tool like maven or gradle? At your link I read

> Although it is strongly recommended that Spring Framework users take advantage of the transitive dependency management features of build systems like Gradle, Maven, and Ivy, some teams cannot use these tools. This is usually due to corporate restrictions or working with legacy builds

Using tool defined above simply the build and the mantainence to a spring project. Then to start with a spring project you can following this [Building Spring Project](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)

Comment: thanks for your answer and I will try another way to build Spring project

Comment: That is totally not an answer. The question is how to build spring distribution with dependencies (for whatever reasons), and an official guide leads to errors. All I am able to find in this regard is this thread that just suggests me not to.